# Css hover from codepen goes berzerk if html is added above

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I found a great codepen for displaying team members.  The problem, when you add html above it, the hover effects go berzerk. You should only get hover effects when you hover over a person (which is exactly what happens in the original code pen: http://codepen.io/solutiondrop/pen/IqKhk)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/npe3lft.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>

<div class="wrapper--team">
<div class="l-container">

  <div class="team-grid">

    <div class="team-grid__member hover">
      <div class="member__info">
        <div class="center-vert-content">
          <h3 class="member__name">Robert Finkel</h3>
          <p class="member__title">Rootmaster</p>
          <a class="member__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3393/robert-finkel_2.jpg" alt="Robert Finkel">
    </div>

    <div class="team-grid__member hover">
      <div class="member__info">
        <div class="center-vert-content">
          <h3 class="member__name">Randy Mosher</h3>
          <p class="member__title">Alchemist</p>
          <a class="member__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3393/randy-mosher.jpg" alt="Randy Mosher">
    </div>

    <div class="team-grid__member hover">
      <div class="member__info">
        <div class="center-vert-content">
          <h3 class="member__name">BJ Pichman</h3>
          <p class="member__title">Operations Manager</p>
          <a class="member__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3393/mrch8596.jpg" alt="BJ Pichman">
    </div>

    <div class="team-grid__member hover">
      <div class="member__info">
        <div class="center-vert-content">
          <h3 class="member__name">Jacqueline Armanetti</h3>
          <p class="member__title">Brand Ambassador</p>
          <a class="member__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3393/jacqueline-armanetti.jpg" alt="Jacqueline Armanetti">
    </div>

    <div class="team-grid__member hover">
      <div class="member__info">
        <div class="center-vert-content">
          <h3 class="member__name">Romy Seth</h3>
          <p class="member__title">Analyst</p>
          <a class="member__link" href="javascript:void(0)">Read More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3393/romy-seth.jpg" alt="Romy Seth">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

However, when I add a little html above the original html in my own implementation, (like the two divs below the hover) behavior breaks.

```
<div></div>
<div><span><br>if you hover on this text on the white region over the images,
weird stuff happens. <br>The javascript should only be triggered if you  hover over a person (scroll down to see)</span>
</div>
```

After I add my little divs above the fancy codepen stuff, the pages provides information when you hover on the new, preceding white-region, instead of when you hover over the team member. Here is the codepen showing the broken version, with the little bit of preceding html: http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/zqqyVj .

Why on earth could this be happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `.member-info` class... Use chrome developer tools to easily debug this problem.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGGNmd#0

Your CSS:

```
.member__info {
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);

  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

my recommendation:

```
.member__info {
  color: #fff;
  height: 184px;
  width: 184px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to fix that, what is the problem?

Comment: in which way? I don't know what it should be like, I don't understand what is wrong with the class or how to fix it.

Comment: I implemented your changes, it now responds only when hovering over the team members, but it does two things that are undesirable: 1) it provides info above the members instead of over them, and 2) the fourth member is shifted (both in my implementation and in the code pen). (See the updated second code pen) I appreciate your help, and I like learning, but this is beyond my knowledge, and that is why I asked for help.

Comment: Although this had nothing to do with your original question, I edited my answer above to fix those issues. Again, please use chrome developer tools to fix issues like this in the future (and to help you with learning front end web development in general)

Comment: I do try to solve everything that I understand with the chrome tools, but there were too many moving parts on this.  Thank you for your help!  It would be perfect if the hovers were inside the frames but your changes are amazing.  Thank you!

Comment: This version is no longer on the frame, did you edit it?  Briefly there was a version you posted that worked, but now things have since shifted before i was able to grab the code.

Comment: I see the pixels for .member info need to change in a media responsive way, I can do that.  thank you!!! I'm sorry I was so confused.  I appreciate what you did